# Why are my CheckBoxe's state never saved?

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox

I have a few `CheckBox` elements inside one of my `Fragments`.

Every time I leave this Fragment it seems to nor save or restore the checked state of each one provided by the user.

In the `FragmentList` example you can find:

```
CheckBox check1;
boolean active;
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("state1", check1.isChecked());
    }
```

Which you can use later like this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            check1.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("state1"));
        }
}
```

But somehow the `CheckBox` elements don`t save their state.

Is this the correct approach I should take?

Comment: Use `onRestoreInstanceState()` to restore the saved state.

Comment: Still not saving the CheckBox state.

Comment: After setting a Toast inside of it I can notice they`re never called actually.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're keeping your Fragment reference alive through the lifecycle of the application, it should be fine to save its state in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it in `onActivityCreated`.

One important point, though, is also to save and restore that state in the `Activity` level by doing like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore the fragment's instance
        mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(
                savedInstanceState, "fragKey");
        ...
    }
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Save the fragment's instance
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragKey", mContent);
}
```

Please check to see how your `Activity` is behaving in your scenario.